# flex vs. flash startup times

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I've recently started using flex4 and have found when I compile a
file, the swf generated takes a lot longer to startup than a swf
generated with flash.

When the flex swf is run there is always a progress bar, which I'm
assuming is initializing different things, but this doesn't happen
with swf's made with flash...

Any ideas why ? or what I can disable to prevent this.

I basically want my swf to run as fast as possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Flex SDK includes many classes needed to provide Flex Framework functionality (layout, components, resources, lifecycle, utilities). That's why your swf needs to load additional data. You should get familiar with Flex framework itself, its advantages and functionality.

Also read about using [RSLs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_09.html). I'm sure, it will help you to decrease startup time.

Comment: RSLs may decrease load time if the Signed Framework RSLs are cached by the Flash Player, but I do not believe they would affect the framework setup time.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, if they are cached, there would be no need to load them again. So, startup time will be less after the first run. Am I missing something?

Comment: I was trying to make a clarification.  Startup time, in my world, is the time between loading the SWF and being able to use the app.  Framework setup time is the actual act of loading classes and initializing the framework; and would only be a subset of setup time.  I thought the progress bar wasn't shown until after the framework RSLs were loaded; thus using RSLs may not decrease the time the progress bar is shown.  But, don't quote me on that.